# What is the mathematical term for 'stepping' by a given value.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the many early learner books for young children, things like addition and subtraction are explained as stepping a particular amount. For example, in this number line:

> 1, 3, 5, 7, ...

It is explained that we are 'stepping' up and down by 2. Is there a mathematical term for the amount we move rather than stepping, or to put another way, a more generic mathematical term that covers both "increment by" and "decrement by"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an *arithmetic progression* or *arithmetic sequence* and the amount that you add at each step is called the *common difference* of the progression, because consecutive terms of the progression all have the same difference.

Answer (score 1):

Generating the number line above, in each STEP, "up and down" you must have a difference of $2$: a way, pedagogical I guess, to define an arithmetic progression  for young children.